# Mosby: any onNewViewState() method after Views inflated?

Tags: android, mosby

Now I can call presenter like that to update UI at the first time:

```
@Override
public void onNewViewStateInstance() {
    presenter.initialize();
}
```

in `Presenter`:

```
@Override
public void initialize() {
    getView().setColor(projectManager.getProject().getColor());
    getView().setEditMenuItemEnabled(projectManager.getProject().isOpened());
}
```

And I always must wrap code with `Handler.post` to avoid executing this code *before* `Views` is inflated.

```
@Override
public void setEditMenuItemEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    getViewState().setEditEnabled(enabled);
    handler.post(() -> {
        editMenuItem.setEnabled(enabled);
        ViewUtils.makeItLooksEnabled(editMenuItem.getIcon(), enabled);
    });
}
```

Any solution to avoid using `Handler` in every `View`?

Comment: This should not be the case, because ViewState will be instantiated / restored after `Activity.onCreate()` or `Fragment.onViewCreated()`. Please report this issue on github's issue tracker. Please write which version of Mosby and support library. https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/issues